# WP mail - Delivery failed: unknown error, how to debug?

Tags: php, wordpress, email, postfix-mta

I have a cron-job on a server that runs every Friday at noon. It Bcc's a list of recipients which corresponds to a list of users in a WordPress instance - the list may constantly be changing (e-mail addresses may be removed and added each time the job is runs). The function  to send the actual e-mail message is [`wp_mail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail) which uses php's built in `mail()`.

The job has been running fine for a few weeks until recently where all I get is the following error:

`Delivery failed: unknown error`

I've tried to run the script via command line using the `php` command and it outputs the same error. I've tried debugging it using only my e-mail address as the only recipient, and it works fine which leads me to believe that it's an issue with one of the e-mail addresses in the list of email addresses.

My questions are, how can I debug such an ambiguous error message? Secondly, how can I find the "culprit" e-mail address that may be causing the problems? Is there a way to disable postfix so `wp_mail` doesn't actually send out any e-mails?

Here is the code that sends out the e-mails:

```
<?php

// Get all user emails
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'fields' => array( 'ID', 'user_email' ) ) );

if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
    $recipients = array();
    $members = $user_query->results;

    // sort according to last name
    usort($members, create_function('$a, $b', 'return strnatcasecmp($a->last_name, $b->last_name);'));

    foreach ( $members as $member ) {
        if( get_the_author_meta( "active_user", $member->ID )  == "yes" ){

          if ( filter_var($member->user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
            array_push( $recipients, $member->user_email );
      }else{
        echo $member->user_email . ' is an invalid email!' . PHP_EOL;
      }
        }
    }
}
// Build and send the reminder email
if( !empty( $settings['weekly_email']) ){

    add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' );
    function set_html_content_type() {
        return 'text/html';
    }

    $reminder_message = 'This is your reminder...'
    $headers = 'From: Reminder bot <reminderbot@somedomain.com>' . "\n";
    $headers .= 'Bcc: ' . implode( ',', $recipients ) . "\r\n";
    wp_mail( 'reminderbot@somedomain.com', 'Your reminder', $reminder_message, $headers );

    // Reset content-type to avoid conflicts -- http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23578
    remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' );
}
```

Comment: As you already found out, these things are hard to debug. You just need to put a lot of efforts into it as it only fails when it fails. What can help is that you create a logfile that lists all emails when it fails so you can then check those adresses. However the way you compile up the headres, especially BCC, might be the culprit. Take care to not mix `\r\n` and `\n` only sequences. Take `\r\n` always - but that must not be the cause of your problem. Just saying.

Comment: first thing i would check would be the mail server logs

Comment: The servers logs are empty as it hasn't been sending any mail. Also, I checked the php error logs and nothing comes up. I decided to try and run wp_mail() for each user separately which obviously is not efficient - but it seems to work if I call it separately which leads me to believe the way formatted the Bcc incorrectly...